# Excel round date to specific day

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

I have a list with days that I want to round to specific weekdays depending on the input day.

So let's say this is the list:

- 2024-01-01 (Monday)
- 2024-01-02 (Tuesday)
- 2024-01-03 (Wednesday)
- 2024-01-04 (Thursday)
- 2024-01-05 (Friday)

I want to round the days to Monday/Wednesday/Friday.
If the date is Tuesday it should round to Wednesday and if the date is Thursday it should round to Friday!

I can do this:

```
=WORKDAY(A1-1;1)
```

Which takes a day from the current workday and ads another.
Problem is that I would like to round it to a specific day.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you rounding up or rounding down?

Comment: Where would Tuesday/Thursday belong to? Both to the previous day?

Comment: @Enigmativity. Up....

Comment: @Notus_Panda. The next day. I'll update the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this works:

```
=A1+MOD(MOD(WEEKDAY(A1)+5,7),2)
```

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: @Interactive So you need Sat & Sun? that was not clear in your question.

Comment: @SolarMike No only weekdays

Comment: I assumed it didn't matter. A simple `IF` would allow Saturday to be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

[image]

The days etc are formatted as dates or custom "DDDD"

Note you could deal with Sat and Sun similarly - I just stuck to Mon-Fri.